# Changing SQL statement based on which VBA listbox is currently selected

Tags: sql, vba, ms-word

I have a userform called Attendance that has two listboxes on it. One called Seated, one called NotSeated.

In a SQL column everyone starts the day off as '1'. If someone is here today they get marked as '2', if they aren't they get marked as a '3' or a '4'.

I have a reset button that I want to have reset them to '1' when pressed. What I need to be able to do is to change my UPDATE query based on which listbox the user has currently highlighted. Here is what I have so far, but it's not working.

```
Sub resetagent()
database_connect
Dim AttendRecord As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim Cm As ADODB.Command
If appconn.State = 0 Then
Call database_connect
End If
Set Cm = New ADODB.Command
With Cm
    .ActiveConnection = appconn
    If attendance.Seated.value <> "" Then
    .CommandText = "UPDATE [Attendance] SET [Seated] = '1' WHERE [Agentname]= '" & attendance.Seated.value & "'"
    ElseIf attendance.NotSeated.value <> "" Then
    .CommandText = "UPDATE [Attendance] SET [Seated] = '1' WHERE [Agentname]= '" & attendance.NotSeated.value & "'"
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .Execute
End If
End With
Set AttendRecord = Nothing
database_Disconnect
End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like the last `End If` is in the wrong spot.  Move it up 2 lines, just after the second `CommandText`.

Comment: That fixed it. I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.Execute` is sitting inside your if statement and can only run if you are in the `Else` portion of the statement. Move the `End if`statement up 2 lines.

Also if both list boxes are not blank (i.e. one is a '1' and the other is a '3') then it would not match either of the `If` statement conditions and do nothing here.

One you move the `End If` line, it would execute whatever the button's defaulted `CommandText` is.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you!